# Sencha Touch nested list not getting refreshed after adding data to tree store

Tags: sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

I have a sencha app that has a nested view. If i hard code the data inline in the store, the view gets populated. But if I create the data(json) dynamically and add it to the store, nothing happens. The view does not get refreshed even though the store seems to have the data.

I have a view of **xtype** : **nestedlist**

```
items:[{
xtype: 'nestedlist',
store: 'MyNestedStore',
title: 'My nested list',
itemTpl: [
'<div  class=""><span>{text} </span><span></div>',
],
```

**Store:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyNestedStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
config: {
model: 'MyApp.model.MyNestedStore',
defaultRootProperty: 'data',
    data: [{
        category_id: 1,
        text: 'Clothing',
            data:[{
                category_id: 1,
                sub_category_id: 1,
                text: 'Tops and Tees',
                leaf:true,
                },{
                category_id: 1,
                sub_category_id: 2,
                text: 'Casual Shirts',
                leaf:true,
            }]
    }, {
        category_id: 2,
        text: 'Footwear',
            data:[{
                category_id: 2,
                sub_category_id: 1,
                text: 'Casual Shoes',
                leaf:true,
            }]
    }]  
}
});
```

Up to this point, it works fine where I have the data defined inline in the store.

What if I want the very same data to be added dynamically?

I tried to add this data but the view (nestedlist) would not get refreshed.

eg:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('MyNestedStore');
store.removeAll();  // works fine

store.add([{
        category_id: 1,
        text: 'Clothing',
            data:[{
                category_id: 1,
                sub_category_id: 1,
                text: 'Tops and Tees',
                leaf:true,
                },{
                category_id: 1,
                sub_category_id: 2,
                text: 'Casual Shirts',
                leaf:true,
            }]
    }, {
        category_id: 2,
        text: 'Footwear',
            data:[{
                category_id: 2,
                sub_category_id: 1,
                text: 'Casual Shoes',
                leaf:true,
            }]
    }]) //data added to store but view did not get refreshed.
```

I tried auto load and auto sync on the store. Nothing happens. Help !

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Added the config, layout: 'fit' to the parent panels that contains the nested list view.